# How to pass data(base64 - string) to previous screen in Flutter using Navigator?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application in which I want to take a photo and send it to the server. To do this, I use the term base46. When I press the button, I go to the page where the camera is open, where I take a photo and convert it to base64 format. But the problem is that I can't return this term to the previous page. Here is the part of the code in which I go to the page with the camera:

```dart
Expanded(
    child: ButtonTheme(
        alignedDropdown: true,
        child: new RaisedButton.icon(
        label: Text('Add image'),
        onPressed: () {Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => image.PicturePreview(camera)),
            );
        },
        icon : Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        )
    ),
),
```

And here is the page where the term is converted(_imageB64 ). I will be grateful for the help)

```dart
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


    class PicturePreview extends StatefulWidget {
      final CameraDescription camera;
      const PicturePreview(this.camera, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _PicturePreviewState createState() => _PicturePreviewState();
    }
    class _PicturePreviewState extends State<PicturePreview> {

      CameraController _controller;
      Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

      @override
      String _imageB64;
      File _image;
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // To display the current output from the Camera,
        // create a CameraController.
        _controller = CameraController(
          // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
          widget.camera,
          // Define the resolution to use.
          ResolutionPreset.medium,
        );

        // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
        _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
        _controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: FutureBuilder<void>(
            future: _initializeControllerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
                return CameraPreview(_controller);
              } else {
                // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            // Provide an onPressed callback.
            onPressed: () async {
              // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
              // catch the error.
              try {
                // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
                await _initializeControllerFuture;

                // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
                // where it was saved.
                final image = await _controller.takePicture();
                _image = File(image.path);
                List<int> imageBytes = _image.readAsBytesSync();
                _imageB64 = base64Encode(imageBytes);
                 
              } catch (e) {
                // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
                print(e);
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using `String imageB64 = await Navigator.push(...)` in the first page, and  `Navigator.pop(context, _imageB64)` in `_PicturePreviewState`?

Comment: @MagnusW     yes ,but  await  it doesn't work

Comment: @MagnusW                           onPressed: () {
                            String imageB64 = await  Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => image.PicturePreview(camera)),
                             );
                          },

Comment: `await` does work - why do you say it does not?

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak It should work, but of course you need to change  `onPressed: (){` to `onPressed: () async {` to be able to use `await` inside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to close the camera page and go back to the previous page while returning the result, you can return the Base64-encoded string using `Navigator.of(context).pop(_imageB64)`.

First, change the calling code to

```
onPressed: () async {
  String imageB64 = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => image.PicturePreview(camera)),
  );

  // Now you can do whatever you want with the Base64-encoded image
},
```

Then, in your camera screen, you can return the image when closing the screen:

```
onPressed: () async {
  // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
  // catch the error.
  try {
    // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
    await _initializeControllerFuture;

    // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
    // where it was saved.
    final image = await _controller.takePicture();
    _image = File(image.path);
    List<int> imageBytes = _image.readAsBytesSync();
    _imageB64 = base64Encode(imageBytes);

     // Close the page and return the result
     Navigator.of(context).pop(_imageB64);
  } catch (e) {
    // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
    print(e);
  }
},
```

Comment: so thank you it helped me, but I still have a question when this variable returns, and it is not null, I would like to write in a variable _photo name "timeshtamp.img". Because it was not clear whether the base returned or not)

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak I'm not sure exactly what you mean by _"write in a variable _photo name "timeshtamp.img"_? Anyway it sounds like a separate question from this one, so you should try to find an existing answer or open a new question.

Comment: I created a new question, I will be grateful for help) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66818118/update-the-variable-depending-on-what-data-was-returned-from-the-previous-screen