# Update the variable depending on what data was returned from the previous screen in Flutter using the Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable _PhotoName, this variable is null, but when I take a photo and repeat the term base64 from another screen, I would like the variable _PhotoNameto be a timestamp.img , if base64 is not null.
here is the part of the code that displays this variable, and there is also code where base 64 is returned:

```html
              Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                        "$_PhotoName",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15)

                    ),

                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                        alignedDropdown: true,
                        child: new RaisedButton.icon(
                          label: Text('Add Image'),//Добавити фото
                          onPressed: () async{
                            _imageB64 = await  Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => image.PicturePreview(camera)),
                             );

                          },

                          icon : Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                        )
                    ),
                  ),

                ],

              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have not understood the question but you could check if `base64` is `null` and if so update the state

```
if (_imageB64 != null) {
    setState ((){
        _PhotoName = WHAT_IT_NEEDS_TO_BE_EQUAL_TO;
    });
}
```